# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined react js

Tags: reactjs

I am getting this error while rendering, I am new to React JS , Please tell me what error I am making in mapping?
Please Help out. I am using axios. and I am trying to fetch the data from //https://www.reddit.com/r/space.json

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class Apicall extends Component {


  componentWillMount(){
    this.getReddit();
  }

  getReddit(){
    axios.get(`https://www.reddit.com/r/${this.state.subr}.json`)

    .then(res =>{
      const posts = res.data.data.children.map(obj =>obj.data);
      this.setState({posts});
    });

  }

  constructor(props){
    super(props);


    this.state = {
      post:[],
      subr:'space'
    };
    this.getReddit = this.getReddit.bind(this);
  }






  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <h1>{`/r/${this.state.subr}`}</h1>
        <ul>
          {this.state.posts.map(post =>
            <li key={post.id}>{post.title}</li>

          )}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default Apicall;
```

Comment: typo, state variable name is `post`, inside render method you are using `posts.map`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When posting in the future, please include the full error that you're experiencing. It contains useful information like line numbers.

I can see that either

`this.state.posts`
or
`res.data.data.children`

Must be returning null in order for that error to occur, as they both have the `map` function called on them.

`this.state.posts` specifically is plural, while the state is defined using the singular form:

```
this.state = {
  post:[],
  subr:'space'
};
```

So renaming it to the plural version could fix the error you've described

```
this.state = {
  posts:[],
  subr:'space'
};
```

Comment: Thanks, @Sean  that was a really silly mistake to do :(

Comment: Glad I could help @DeeprajMaurya we all make mistakes! If the solution worked please consider accepting the answer :).